# Exact styling of a difference in time (php)

Tags: php, datetime

It's easy to get the difference in minutes and seconds from two times (format: `H:i:s`), I got that from another question on this site.

I tried it this way:

```
$start_date = new DateTime('04:10:58');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->h.':';
echo $since_start->i.':';
echo $since_start->s;
```

But that outputs:

> 6:14:2

I think that doesn't look good. I want it to look like: `06:14:02`

I also want to use the current time instead of a given time, but with above code that doesn't work I noticed.

```
$start_date = date("H:i:s");
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->h.':';
echo $since_start->i.':';
echo $since_start->s;
```

That outputs:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object

The two times I have:
One time is the current time: `date("H:i:s")`, the other one is `$time0` which contains for example a time `11:24:00` (from a database).

Comment: The problem is obvious this time, but please post your actual PHP errors instead of stating "Gives an error." They actually mean stuff!

Comment: Sorry, of course you're right! I was being lazy again...

Comment: I edited the question, I hope that was the right thing to do. PS I didn't know about using the `` too, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Tweaked it a bit further but that's great work, thanks for your effort towards posterity! Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internals of `DateInterval` are unformatted, and you should be using the [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) function:

```
$start_date = new DateTime('04:10:58');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

For the second example, you're using a PHP string (since `date()` returns a string, not an object) and trying to treat it like the `DateTime` object which is why you're getting the error. You should instead initialize an empty `DateTime` object which will default to `now`:

```
$start_date = new DateTime(); // or DateTime('now')
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

If you're initiating a `$start_date` value from a database, let's say `$time0`, you can pass that directly into the `DateTime` construct, which will take a good stab at converting it to a proper `DateTime` object:

```
$start_date = new DateTime($time0);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: Both my questions answered at once! You helped very much with explaining the difference between strings and objects. And it was those %-signs I was missing when I tried capitals, that's a neat little trick!

Comment: @PHPirate Yep, the `DateInterval` uses a completely different set of formatting conventions (you can take a look at the reference link I provided to see more information.) Great effort with the `DateTime` objects though, a lot of beginners don't think to use the OO way and instead try to wrangle with `date` and `strtotime`. Best of luck!